# How to change particle effect color?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

How can I change the color of the particle system to be same as my player color?

I tried to find on some tutorials how to do it and I got this solution:

```
GameObject effectBlow = Instantiate(blowOut, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
effectBlow.gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = material.material.color;
```

But now my Unity is complaining about that code and it says it's obsolete and of course colors don't change in game.

I don't know how to change it, can somebody help me ?

Comment: Are you attached this script to Player gameobject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**startColor** property is deprecated,so it can't be used like that, try this code

```
        GameObject effectBlow = Instantiate(blowOut, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        var main = effectBlow.gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main;
        main.startColor = player.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
```

So what it basically does is it create a variable **main** and the instantiated gameobject's particleSystem main module will be refereed to it from that main variable we use **startColor** property to modify the color of player gameobject

For more info check this out : 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-main.html

Comment: Adding to your answer that the particle system sprite used for the material must be fully white if you want to apply a color, if not it the color will be mixed with the color of the sprite (speaking about unity2D, I guess in Unity3D happens too).